# Measuring pixel width of table in watir-webdriver

Tags: html-table, width, pixel, watir-webdriver, dimension

Is there a way to read the pixel dimensions of a table? Percentage already shows  `width="100%"`. It is inside a div if that helps to probe instead.

I am trying to get the width to then resize the window for a png screenshot (using Watir functions already available). Currently because it shows its own horizontal scrollbar within the page, the table is truncated to only the first few columns in the screenshot, while vertically the entire page appears as usual, regardless of browser window size.

```
$browser.div(:id, "ctl27_divDetailFrame").table.row.cells.length

=> 23
```

shows me that it has 23 columns, though that may vary.

I already shrink the screen font a bit with

`$browser.send_keys :home, [:control, "-"],  [:control, "-"]`

but that is not enough, and the font size shouldn't have to be reduced down to oblivion anyway.

The scraped source:

```
<div id="ctl27_divDetailFrame">
    <div class="detail-table-wrapper">
        <div id="ctl27_pnlPositionsTable">
                        <table class="detail-table w-Positions" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr class="detail-table-head">
                                <td><a class="hpc-column-sort SymbolHeadOSI" href="#" name="DetailSymbolHeader">Symbol</a><span class="common_icon-sort-up-orange_png" title="Sorted Ascending" style="margin-left: 3px; vertical-align:middle;"></span></td>
                                <td class="detail-heading-numeric"><a class="hpc-column-sort SymbolHeadOSI" href="#" name="DetailQuantityHeader">Qty</a></td>
.
.
.
                                <td class="detail-non-numeric"> LAST CELL of table </td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
    </div>
```

Nowhere do I see an explicit  `width="99999px"` which I'd simply be able to read.

2 CORRECTIONs: There is this class defined in one of the css files:
And, horizontal resizing page previously did not extend the table's visibility beyond the  830px.

```
   div.detail-table-wrapper
    {
        width: 830px;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

So now I'd like to see if I can change that **width** to ~ 95% from **watir-webdriver** functions...(keeping it inline with the visible screen, which I can freely resize)

Comment: Can width be read from some Javascript call? Something like `$browser.execute_script('$("##{detail-table w-Positions}").width();')` if I could get that right.

Comment: I'd speak to whomever wrote the html app to see if they can modify it to be more testable.

Comment: Otherwise, could you just resize the browser to something like 3000 wide and take a screenshot?

Comment: Yeah, I could. But it's annoying to end up with a wide screenshot that either still truncates some columns or ends up way too wide by 1000's in wasted margin, since table size varies.  As to your 1st comment, true, but I'm using watir only for running jobs against sites I have no influence over(eg. as bank's customer), not for web testing.

Comment: The width is perhaps controlled by a css style for the table or the div that holds it.

Comment: I was suspecting the answer to lie within styles. Know offhand how I could modify an element's or class's style width prior to screenshot, whether or not it's already explicitly defined in a CSS? Say for example for `<div id="ctl27_divDetailFrame">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Watir-Webdriver for Firefox, I was able to change the  width style to 95% with the following:

```
$browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl27_divDetailFrame')
      .getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].style.width='95%';")
```

Note that the locator is based on the HTML sample. Depending on whether that ID is consistent or not, you might need a better locator. For example, you might be able to do a regex for the ID using http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=59109660 (but I have not tested it).

Aside: With Watir, you could more directly do this with the following code. However, being new to Watir-Webdriver, I could not find a similar document() method.

```
$ie.div(:index, 2).document.style.width = '95%'
```

Comment: Sadly, `$browser.div(:id => "whatever").document` doesn't seem to be available in watir-webdriver, but trying that .execute_script next (which I may have to perform at several levels). Thanks!

Comment: `$browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl27_divDetailFrame').getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].style.width='100%';") ` that worked! Finally got rid of horizontal scrollbar & incomplete screenshot that was thoroughly annoying me. Thanks.